# Gmail API with service account

Tags: ruby, gmail-api, google-api-client

Under `mygmailaccount@gmail.com` in the API console I created a project and I am successfully using a service account for the `Analytics API` and `Search Console API` services. I've now enabled the `Gmail V1` API and ran this code:

```
gmail_scopes = [
  "https://mail.google.com/",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
]
gmail = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
gmail.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(gmail_scopes)
```

This is the same code (with different scopes of course) that I use to authorize the Analytics and Search Console API.

However I get `BAD REQUEST` `Failed Precondition` errors when I run this:

```
gmail.get_user_profile("mygmailaccount@gmail.com")
```

Some googling tells me that is because the API is trying to access the non-existent inbox for the serviceaccount email address and that in the initiatlization process I need to include `mygmailaccount@gmail.com` so that the API service will use that inbox.

How do I do that?

I've tried the following '...' always being the email address

```
gmail.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(gmail_scopes, username: '...')
gmail.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(gmail_scopes, {username: '...'})
gmail.authorization.username = '...'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service accounts cannot access @gmail.com mailboxes.  You need to use an OAuth2 UserAuthorizer.  See the [Gmail API Ruby Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby) for an example.